# How to disable delete and move the 1st cell in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to disable delete and move the 1st cell in UICollectionView. And also other cells in UICollectionView cannot move to the 1st one. How to  implement it？

Comment: Look at the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols. Implement the ones that control editing, deleting, and moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable movement you need to implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol and use this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.item != 0
}
```

Disabling deletion depends totally on your deletion implementation.